# Chart.js 2.x draw something after bars and before tooltip to avoid overlap

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need draw something over the bars, I made it but when tooltip appear it shown behind my text, not over. I need some event like beforetooltiprender

Comment: Try writing some CSS. The tooltip will most likely be positioned absolutely. Use `z-index`

Comment: it is a canvas... css doesn't work